# Как найти указатель позиции текстового блока в ELF файле/секции ELF файла

Tags: ассемблер, elf, linux

Необходимо в исполняемом файле формата ELF заменить текстовый блок (указатель вида кодировки HTML страниц роутера) на блок большего размера. Для этого надо сместить вправо 3 соседних блока, в пределах одной строки. Как найти указатели позиций этих блоков и изменить их?

Answer (score 2):

Текстовые блоки в исполняемом elf-файле как правило хранятся в секции *.rodata* (read only data). Ссылки (указатели) на начальные адреса позиций используемых текстовых блоков находятся в секции инструкций *.text*. Следовательно, если надо переместить начало блока (вправо или влево), надо соответственно изменить указатели адресов.

С этой проблемой часто сталкиваются русификаторщики программ. Например, слово **«сохранить»** длиннее, чем его английский аналог **«save»**. Между соседними текстовыми блоками должен быть разделитель (хотя бы один нулевой байт). Если изменяемый текстовый блок помещается в отведенный размер (при этом должен остаться как минимум один нулевой байт перед следующим блоком), проблем нет — можно править. Но если конец изменяемого блока заходит на начало соседней (справа) позиции, придется изменять указатели на эту позицию.

Пример, с которым работал я: исполняемый elf-файл, формат — big endian, процессор — MIPS32:

```
             0 1 2 3  4 5 6 7  8 9 A B  C D E F                                      

  4d6a30:   6d696d6f 00000000 73686f77 73734755     mimo....showssGU
  4d6a40:   49000000 64736c56 65727369 6f6e0000     I...dslVersion..
  4d6a50:   68746d6c 63686172 73657400 49534f2d     htmlcharset.ISO-
  4d6a60:   38383539 2d310000 4249472d 35000000     8859-1..BIG-5...
  4d6a70:   53757043 484c616e 67000000 636f6e6e     SupCHLang...conn
  4d6a80:   65637449 6e666f00 636f6e63 6f756e74     ectInfo.concount
```

1. Надо сдвинуть влево блок «BIG-5». Слева есть два нулевых байта, значит двигать можно. Начальная позиция *4d6a**68*** должна измениться на *4d6a**67***. Надо найти указатель на эту позицию в секции *.text* Можно сделать это вручную (поискать HEX-значение `6A 68`). Но лучше использовать дизассемблер (например IDA PRO). Дизассемблируем и находим соответствующую позицию в секции *.rodata*:

   > .rodata:004D6A66 byte_4D6A66:     .byte 0          # DATA XREF: cgiGetVar+F8r
   >
   > .rodata:004D6A67      .align 2
   >
   > .rodata:004**D6A68** aBig5:   .ascii "BIG-5"<0>        # DATA XREF: cgiGetVar+C4o
   >
   > .rodata:004D6A68                   # cgiGetVar+C8r ...
   >
   > .rodata:004D6A6E      .align 4
   >
   > .rodata:004D6A70 aSupchlang:  .ascii "SupCHLang"<0>    # DATA XREF: cgiGetVar+130o
   >
   > .rodata:004D6A7A      .align 2
2. Проходим по ссылке (`cgiGetVar +...`) и попадаем в соответствующий раздел секции 
   *.text*:

   > .text:00489060              la      $v0, 0x4D0000
   >
   > .text:00489064              la      $v0, 0x4D0000
   >
   > .text:004**89068**          addiu   $v1, $v0, (aBig5 - 0x4D0000)  # **"BIG-5"**
   >
   > .text:004**8906C**          lw      $v0, (aBig5 - 0x4D0000)($v0)  # **"BIG-5"**
   >
   > .text:00489070              lbu     $a0, (aBig5+5 - 0x4D6A68)($v1)
   >
   > .text:00489074              lbu     $v1, (aBig5+4 - 0x4D6A68)($v1)
   >
   > .text:00489078              swl     $v0, 0($s1)
   >
   > .text:0048907C              swr     $v0, 3($s1)
   >
   > .text:00489080              sb      $a0, 5($s1)
   >
   > .text:00489084              b       loc_48A190
   >
   > .text:00489088              sb      $v1, 4($s1)
3. Находим соответствующий адрес HEX редактором. Адрес *00489068* ищем как *00089068*:

   ```
              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F  
   00089050  8f 82 8a 1c 8c 43 00 00  24 02 00 01 14 62 00 0b  |.....C..$....b..|
   00089060  8f 82 80 28 8f 82 80 28  24 43 6A 68 8c 42 6a 68  |...(...($Cjh.Bjh|
   00089070  90 64 00 05 90 63 00 04  aa 22 00 00 ba 22 00 03  |.d...c..."..."..|
   00089080  a2 24 00 05 10 00 04 42  a2 23 00 04 8c 43 6a 5c  |.$.....B.#...Cj\|
   00089090  24 42 6a 5c 8c 44 00 04  aa 23 00 00 90 45 00 0a  |$Bj\.D...#...E..|
   000890a0  90 46 00 08 90 42 00 09  ba 23 00 03 aa 24 00 04  |.F...B...#...$..|
   000890b0  ba 24 00 07 a2 25 00 0a  a2 26 00 08 10 00 04 34  |.$...%...&.....4|
   000890c0  a2 22 00 09 8f 85 80 28  8f 99 89 cc 02 40 20 21  |.".....(.....@ !|
   ```

   IDA PRO к адресу позиции добавляет 4, вместо 0 в привычном HEX.
4. Видим сразу два (!) указателя на соответствующую позицию (*D6A68*) — *24 43 **6A 68** 8c 42 **6a 68***. Меняем оба на *24 43 **6A 67** 8c 42 **6a 67***. Сохраняем файл. Можно запускать.

В приведенном примере использован файл формата *big endian* — байты пишутся прямым порядком (и без смещения на величину заголовка). Если есть смещение, его надо учитывать при поиске и обозначении позиций. Если используется формат *little endian*, надо писать байты в обратном порядке.

В статье [«Работаем со смещениями - расширяем горизонты!»](http://www.pspx.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=83903)<sup>[[архив](https://web.archive.org/web/20161009175532/http://www.pspx.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=83903)]</sup> есть похожий пример, который и вдохновил на изменение elf файла.

Answer (score 0):

Получить адреса секций elf-файла можно вызовом команды readelf или objdump.

Получить адреса вызовов в коде, которые могут использовать ту или иную секцию, относительно трудно. Для этого надо анализировать таблицы plt и got. Чтобы понять как это делать точно, надо смотреть спецификацию.

Вообще перемещение и изменение размеров секций в ряде случаев удается командой objcopy.

Comment: @тимур Секцию я определил (.rodata) адрес начала блока знаю. Подскажите как вызвать таблицы plt/got плз.спсб