# Изменение указателя количества обрабатываемых байтов в ассемблере под MIPS32

Tags: mips, ассемблер, elf, html, linux

Помогите разобраться с дизассемблированным кодом. Исходный файл исполняемый, формата ELF. процессора MIPS32. (управляющая программа роутера. исходников нет). Задача - заменить указатель кодировки языка web страниц с BIG-5 на ISO-5589-5. Исходное слово короче заменяемого на 5 символов. Находится в секции .rodata. 
Вот соответствующий фрагмент в hex

```
  4d6a50:   68746d6c 63686172 73657400 49534f2d     htmlcharset.ISO-
  4d6a60:   38383539 2d310000 4249472d 35000000     8859-1..BIG-5...
  4d6a70:   53757043 484c616e 67000000 636f6e6e     SupCHLang...conn
```

Чтобы не залезать на соседний (справа) текстовый блок я изменил указатель позиций этого блока в секции инструкций .text (подробнее - здесь [Как найти указатель позиции текстового блока в ELF файле/секции ELF файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33729/)) Вот фрагмент дизассемблированной (IDA PRO) секции .text c соответствующей инструкцией.

```
.text:00489060             la      $v0, 0x4D0000

.text:00489064             la      $v0, 0x4D0000

.text:00489068             addiu   $v1, $v0, (aBig5 - 0x4D0000)  # "BIG-5"

.text:0048906C             lw      $v0, (aBig5 - 0x4D0000)($v0)  # "BIG-5"

.text:00489070             lbu     $a0, (aBig5+5 - 0x4D6A68)($v1)

.text:00489074             lbu     $v1, (aBig5+4 - 0x4D6A68)($v1)

.text:00489078             swl     $v0, 0($s1)

.text:0048907C             swr     $v0, 3($s1)

.text:00489080             sb      $a0, 5($s1)

.text:00489084             b       loc_48A190

.text:00489088             sb      $v1, 4($s1)

.text:0048908C  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

.text:0048908C

.text:0048908C loc_48908C:              # CODE XREF: cgiGetVar+B8j

.text:0048908C             lw      $v1, (dword_4D6A5C - 0x4D0000)($v0) #"ISO-"

.text:00489090             addiu   $v0, (dword_4D6A5C - 0x4D0000)

.text:00489094             lw      $a0, (dword_4D6A60 - 0x4D6A5C)($v0) #"8859" 

.text:00489098             swl     $v1, 0($s1)

.text:0048909C             lbu     $a1, (byte_4D6A66 - 0x4D6A5C)($v0)  # нулевой байт

.text:004890A0             lbu     $a2, (byte_4D6A64 - 0x4D6A5C)($v0)  # "-"

.text:004890A4             lbu     $v0, (byte_4D6A65 - 0x4D6A5C)($v0)  # "1"

.text:004890A8             swr     $v1, 3($s1)

.text:004890AC             swl     $a0, 4($s1)

.text:004890B0             swr     $a0, 7($s1)

.text:004890B4             sb      $a1, 0xA($s1)

.text:004890B8             sb      $a2, 8($s1)

.text:004890BC             b       loc_48A190

.text:004890C0             sb      $v0, 9($s1)

.text:004890C4  #
```

---

Проблема в том, что при загрузке обрабатываются только 6 символов (ISO-88). Помогите разобраться с листингом и изменить указатель количества обрататываемых байтов.

Comment: Снимаю шляпу

Comment: @mikillskegg Спасибо, еще бы с командами разобраться, особенно интересует вот это `lbu     $a0, (aBig5+5 - 0x4D6A68)($v1)` и вот это `lbu     $v1, (aBig5+4 - 0x4D6A68)($v1)` :)

Comment: Просьба модераторам не упрощать заголовок вопроса. Проблема не в изменении самого указателя кодировки web-страниц, а в его правильном отображении, это больше по части команд ассемблера для MIPS32!

Comment: Я думаю, надо взять справочник по ассемблеру для MIPS32 и вперед

Comment: @mikillskegg Взял "MIPS Assembly Language Programmer’s Guide", но, пока далеко не все ясно. Потому и прошу помощи. Похоже, что знание ассемблер, да еще под mips - большая редкость :(

Comment: Знание ассемблера под x86 и ч86_64 - не редкость, его все программисты должны проходить, а вот под другие платформы - да, редкость.